# Android program crashes on Froyo, but not on Kitkat

Tags: android, logcat, android-2.2-froyo, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm creating a weather application for android. The application uses `Wifi and Network` provider to get location. The program runs without any errors sometimes. Mostly after I turn off the device and run it again, but if I am running it from eclipse right after a successful run then the errors above appear.

The app runs on Android version `4.4.2`, but crashes on `Android 2.2`.

The minimum SDK version is 8 which is in accordance with `Froyo`.

Logcat warning and error :

```
03-22 23:41:48.471: W/dalvikvm(7332): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:412)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at com.dobbymon.rainguard.MainActivity$AsyncCaller.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:549)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at com.dobbymon.rainguard.MainActivity$AsyncCaller.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
03-22 23:41:48.538: E/AndroidRuntime(7332):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Possible error code:

```
int gb=0;

                  String geocode="";
                      try {


                          geocode = new Scanner(new URL("http://freegeoip.net/xml/").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
                     System.out.println("geocode ="+geocode);
                      gb=geocode.length();
                      System.out.println("gb= "+gb);
                      } catch (Exception e) {


                      }

                      InputSource source2 = new InputSource(new StringReader(geocode));

                      try{
                       nameofplace = xpath.evaluate("/Response/City", source2);

                       System.out.println("nameofplace ="+nameofplace);

                      }
                      catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
```

Comment: You need to post the piece of code that is generating this error

Comment: You try to parse an empty String to an int

Comment: The result of your async task (`onPostExecute`) is an empty string `''` you then attempt to parse this into an Integer, tut tut. Try `result.isEmpty() ? 0 : parse`

Comment: A very important thing I forgot to mention. The program runs without any errors sometimes.Mostly after I turn off the device and run it again, but if I am running it from eclipse right after a successful run then the errors above appear.

Comment: A very intersting finding. The program is executing the AsyncTask even before the Location listener class gets the latitude and longitude. This is why the Number Format exception occurs due to parsing the empty string to integer. But, since the program runs fine on the Kitkat and very rarely on Froyo ( When it runs on Froyo, the latitude and longitude are displayed correctly before the async task is executed), is it some priority difference in the Froyo API/ OS.

Comment: Your code is unreliable and unsafely susceptible to minor variations in device behavior.  Understanding the range of those variations is a worthwhile goal, but for production you should protect it against crashing with something such as the simple suggestion in Blundell's comment.